# Negating the 'is' operator with a variable only works with '!' but not with '== false'

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, operators

Why does `(expr is type varname) == false` gives a compile error, but `!(expr is type varname)` compiles?

```cs
public static void Foo(object o)
{
    if(!(o is string s))  // <-- Using '!'
    {
        return;
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(s);  // <-- OK
    
}
public static void Bar(object o)
{
    if((o is string s) == false) // <-- Using '== false'
    {
        return;
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(s);  // <--Error: Use of unassigned local variable 's'
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nYF7b6

Comment: @RaceRalph It doesn't compute the fact that if o isn't a `string`, it will `return` and `s` won't be used for `Console.WriteLine`. They aren't precomputing the code path that will be used

Comment: With C# 9, you can do `if (o is not string s) return;`, if that helps. If it doesn't branch to the `return` statement, `s` is definitely assigned and non-null.

Comment: The why is because it hasn't been built. next question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler isn't (yet) smart enough to spot this case: it doesn't factor things like `== false` into the definite assignment analysis.

This [has been proposed](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4240) by one of the language design team however (see also the linked issues there). It looks like they're currently planning to cover this in C# 10.